# How to find difference of cells with respect to first cell, where first cells are different on two excels?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

How to find difference of cells with respect to first cells, where first cells are different on two excels?

**Table1**

[image: Table1]

**Table2**

[image: Table2]

**Table3**

[image]

Below are the 2 excel sheets (table1 & table2) and I want to create a new sheet like below table3.

Table3 needs to only contain common value from table1 and table2 and needs result as given.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  If the tables are identical (except for the content to be subtracted), just subtract one from the other.  As you fill the rest of the cells, the references will adjust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vlookup minus Vlookup as long as your Subject columns don't change.

Cell L3 formula:

```
    =VLOOKUP($K3,$F$2:$I$5,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP($K3,$A$2:$D$5,2,FALSE)
```

Drag it across then change the lookup column (2 to 3, then 2 to 4) for the second and third subjects. Then drag it down.

[image]